# Oracle db - repeat equal results

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this issue - My query in oracle is for the collaterals to the loans and insurance to the loans - code is this -

```
select dc.comm_file loan_id, -- loan ID
--------Collaterals part
dc.coll_id, --collateral ID 

----------Insurance part
li.pol_number ins_id

from debts_collaterals dc
left join loan_insurances li on substr(dc.comm_file, 1, 6) = li.event and dc.branch = li.branch and li.date_key = to_date(:date, 'yyyymmdd')
and substr(dc.comm_file, 7, 2)  = li.amendm --some loans must not have insurance


where dc.date_key = to_date(:date, 'yyyymmdd')
and dc.product in ('401','402','405')
and  dc.coll_status != 'L'
and dc.comm_status = 'Y'
and li.status = 'E'
and dc.comm_file = '01424401'
```

The result is:

```
loan_id coll_id insurance_id
1424401 1320    00000000000000755500
1424401 1320    00000000000000755501
1424401 1321    00000000000000755500
1424401 1321    00000000000000755501
```

My question is how to show in result 2 rows - not 4 - etc. I want my result to be -

```
loan_id coll_id insurance_id
1424401 1320    00000000000000755500
1424401 1321    00000000000000755501
```

The logic is - 1 person can have 2 or more collaterals to loans, but 0 insurance(in that case in column ins_id value will be NULL) or like up example 2 collaterals and 2 isnsurances -  etc. ins_id is connect only to loan_id - no connection between ins_id and coll_id. For example if 1 person have 3 collaterals to loan and 2 insurances - result should be 3 rows(because loan have 3 collaterals) and in 3rd row ins_id will be NULL, because loan have only 2 insurances.

Comment: What is the logic to determine to show `insurance_id = 00000000000000755500` for `coll_id = 1320` but `00000000000000755501` for the other?

Comment: The logic is - 1 person can have 2 or more collaterals to loans, but 0 insurance or like up example 2 collaterals and 2 isnsurances -  etc. ins_id is connect only to loan_id - no connection between ins_id and coll_id. For example if 1 person have 3 collaterals to loan and 2 insurances - result should be 3 rows - in 3rd row ins_id will be NULL